# Am I using the properties of my matrix correctly in these inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

This may be a silly question, so my apologies. I just wanted to confirm that my reasoning is correct to strengthen my understanding of my topic. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a matrix $A(x)$ defined on a domain $\Omega$ that is a $d \times d$ symmetric matrix with entries in $L^{\infty} (\Omega)$. This matrix satisfies the following inequalities.

$\alpha^{*} (x) |v|^2 \leq v^t A(x) v \leq \beta ^{*} (x) |v|^2$ for $\forall x \in \Omega$ and arbitrary $v \in \boldsymbol{R}^d$

$0 < \alpha \leq \alpha ^{*} (x) \leq \beta ^{*} (x) \leq \beta < \infty$ $\forall x \in \Omega$

I am working on subsets of the domain $w \subset w^* \subset \Omega$ and I have a function $u(x)$ that is in $H^1 _{loc}(w^*) \cap L^2 (w^*)$. I also have a function $\eta (x)$ such that $0 \leq \eta \leq 1$ everywhere in $w^*$.

My questions are as follows:

1. If I am working with the integral $\int _{w} (A(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla u) \eta ^2 dx$, then can I say that because $\nabla u \cdot \nabla u = || \nabla u ||^2 _2 \geq 0$ (the euclidean norm), $\eta ^2 \geq 0$ (by definition), and $A(x)$ is a positive matrix (from the inequalities above) that $$\int _{w} (A(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla u) \eta ^2 dx\leq \int _{w^*} (A(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla u) \eta ^2 dx?$$
2. If I now have the integral $\int _{w^*} u^2 A(x) \nabla \eta \cdot \nabla \eta dx$ can I use the inequalities above to say that  $$\int _{w^*} u^2 A(x) \nabla \eta \cdot \nabla \eta dx \leq \beta \int _{w^*} u^2 \nabla \eta \cdot \nabla \eta dx?$$ This feels like it should hold to me but I'm confused because the above inequality bounds $v^tA(x)v$ not $A(x)$. I've seen people relating this type of stuff to eigenvalues but if someone could further explain this concept I would be grateful.

Comment: inequalities 1 and 2 are both correct. The notation is $v \cdot w = w^Tv = v^T w$.

Comment: @Kakashi Thank you! The confirmation is greatly appreciated. Can you please elaborate more on what you meant in your comment?

Comment: $v^t A(x)v = A(x)v \cdot v$.

Comment: @Kakashi Oh!! So you're saying that since we have $A(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla u $ we can treat the $\nabla u$ like the $v$'s in $v^t A v = A v \cdot v$?

Comment: Yes that is how 2 was obtained

Comment: @Kakashi Thank you very much for your help!